# Title : Xamarin.IOS, C# | Unable to change language from "Arabic" to "French" from WkWebView and UIPrintInteractionController popup

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Whenever we launch the app first time, the default language selected to "Arabic" but in between when we change the language from "Arabic" to "French", then all the view controller language is changed except the content in WkWebView and UIPrintInteractionController popup.

Can anyone let me know how to change language/ locale in WkWebView and UIPrintInteractionController popup ?

In WkWebView, we are loading the pdf file. In this pdf file, we are showing 5 pages [1...5] and as per the requirement, the content should load in "French" as other ViewControllers are loaded with the "French" language except the WkWebView content with the default language in "Arabic".

As I understand, we need to change the locale of the WkWebView to "French" but not finding the lead on how to change the locale from default "Arabic" to "French" the content / WkWebView gets loaded.

Please find the below code snippet of UIPrintInteractionController popup. how i am open the print popup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTVA0.png)

Technology stack : Xamarin.IOS, C#

Any leads / solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change language on ios, you could use the code to change it in Settings.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

For more details, you could refer the link below. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=u2cfuj88

And the video would show the operation. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/403

Comment: It means is it not possible to change the language programmatically, right? we need to open settings or restart the app, right?
Above solution redirect to app settings. so can we open Preferred language page instead of app settings.

Comment: Sometimes, it does not display the language correctly. From  Apple Doc, we prefer to change it in settings.